# Delete subscription using Store REST API v0.9 - WSO2 AM

Tags: rest, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2 1.10 and trying to integrate with Store REST API. The REST API is on v0.9. Until now, I could create an application and subscribe to an API. My problema is when I need to change the tier os this subscription. Following the recommended process, the subscription must be deleted and created again. Using the store page, works as expected, but using the API I got the following error:

```
{
"moreInfo": "",
"code": 403,
"error": [],
"description": "You don't have permission to access the subscription with Id {{UUID}}",
"message": "Forbidden"
}
```

The error happen when I use GET or DELETE methods to requests to:

```
{{BASE_URL}}/api/am/store/v0.9/subscriptions/{{UUID}}
```

It's important to say that others features like the creation of applications and subscriptions works as well, so I belevie that this behavior is a bug. There is some work around or configuration that can fix this?

Comment: How are you authenticating with the API? Please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, I'm authenticated. Other features of the API works as well.

Comment: Can you attach the request you sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the problem. Using DELETE works as expected, the real problem is on GET /applications, that returns subscriptions from others tenant's, randomly. So when I try DELETE, I receive 403 because the subscription is ownered by another tenant.

There is no workaround that I could use, it was necessary think another business solution.